# How to deserialize json to an abstract class in spring-boot

Tags: json, spring-boot

In my Application i have something like this.

```
public class Question{}
public class MCQ extends Question{}
public class TrueAndFalse Question{}
public class Match Question{}
```

and in my RestController i have a service that adds question.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/game/question/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Question addQuuestion(@RequestParam("gameId") long id, @RequestBody Question question)
```

But i get an error when i try to call this service as i send json file with different structures one for MCQ, TrueAndFalse and Match.
so is it possible to deserialize the received json to Question abstract class.
And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom deserializer which will create `Question` instances based on json payload properties.

For example if the `Question` class looks like this:

```
public class Question {

    private final String name;

    @JsonCreator
    Question(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And sub-class `TrueAndFalse`:

```
public class TrueAndFalse extends Question {

    private final String description;

    @JsonCreator
    TrueAndFalse(@JsonProperty("name") String name,
                 @JsonProperty("description") String description) {

        super(name);
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a deserializer, which will create an instance of `TrueAndFale` sub-class by checking if it has `description` property:

```
public class QuestionDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Question> {

    @Override
    public Question deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
        JsonNode tree = codec.readTree(p);

        if (tree.has("description")) {
            return codec.treeToValue(tree, TrueAndFalse.class);
        }

        // Other types...

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot deserialize to a known type");
    }
}
```

And afterwards, make sure to register it on the object mapper:

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Question.class, new QuestionDeserializer());
        return new ObjectMapper().registerModules(module);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying i'll try that and see what happens.

Comment: What if the `question` would be an abstract class?